# warning assignment operator class reference

Tags: c++, class, reference, warnings

i have this code:

```
class ABC{
    public:

        ABC(std::ostream& os) : _os(os) {}
        void operator() (const Stud* course) {
        Stud->print(_os);

        }

        ABC& operator=(const ABC& other); //Declaration of operator=

    private:
        std::ostream& _os;
    };
```

befor i define assignment operator i get warning "assignment operator could not be generated".
i want assignment between object this class do nothing, its just class print in for_each algorithm.

i try write :

```
ABC& operator=(const ABC& other){
     return *this;
  }
```

but still get warning the other not use.
how can i define assignment operator do nothing. (no Use the #pragma warning statement to suppress the warning).

thanks!

Comment: where did you write the body of the assignment operator?

Comment: i write body of assignment operator inline

Comment: i also write this ABC& operator=(const ABC& ){
     return *this;
  } its work but i dont know if its ok

Comment: i see, but i don't follow you why to write a an assignment operator that does nothing... it won't assign anything, right?

Comment: beacuse i need this class for other tasks , and without assignment operator i get warning

Comment: yes you right , beacuse of this i need define assignment operator do nothing.

Comment: @user3630497 Are you using Visual Studio? If so at warning level 4, it will generate a warning when a default assignment operator is not constructed. There are also cases where not constructing an assignment operator is considered normal and it won't generate a warning. An example is when your class has a non-copyable member variable or if it inherits a non-copyable class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the warning about an unused argument, just don't name it:

```
ABC& operator=(const ABC&){
    return *this;
}
```

The reason that the compiler can't generate an assignment operator for your class is that it has a reference variable, and these can only be initialised, never re-assigned.

If you don't *need* an assignment operator, but only added one to make the compiler happy, you can declare it `private` and then not provide an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Few problems in your code...

```
 class ABC
 {
    public:
        ABC(std::ostream& os) : _os(os) {}

        void operator() (const Stud* course) 
        {
           //Stud->print(_os);   // you can't use Stud here - this is wrong
           course->print(_os);
        }

        ABC& operator=(const ABC& other); //Declaration of operator=

    private:
        std::ostream& _os;
    };
```

Additionally, as `operator()` defines `course` as `const Stud*` the `print` method in `Stud` class should be defined as `const` as well.

other than that, the code compiles perfercly.

Comment: yea you right i not copy my code ok, i writed like you, i checked this code in visual stidio 2008 , level 4, and i get warning beacuse assigmnet operator...

Comment: try to remove the format parameter declaration in the assignment operator - define `ABC& operator=(const ABC&) { return *this;}`

Comment: and also, can you post `Stud` class definition?